# Plotting points after imshow changing image size

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to run the example provided [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata), for a custom data.

Calling the same piece of code showed in the given example generates 4 images where the first one is smaller than the others:

```
plt.subplot(221)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(rs.T, extent=(0,xsteps,0,ysteps), origin='lower')
plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], 'k.', ms=1)
plt.title('Original')
plt.subplot(222)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(grid_z0.T, origin='lower')
plt.title('Nearest')
plt.subplot(223)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(grid_z1.T, origin='lower')
plt.title('Linear')
plt.subplot(224)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(grid_z2.T, origin='lower')
plt.title('Cubic')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(6, 6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If I comment the `plt.plot` call after displaying the first image, all plots end having the same size.

I'm wondering how to display the points and keep the same scale for all images.

Comment: Without knowing what `points`, `rs`, and other variables are, it is hard verify your code.  Could you include a simple initialization for these values using `np.random` or similar?

Comment: Set the same `extent` to all of the plots as in the original example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `plt.autoscale(False)` before your call to `plt.plot`.